# Android stop Multiple instance of a same service

Tags: java, android, service

I am using service in my application, the service works fine.but when ever i close the application (press home button) and open the application again multiple instance of the service is created.

What i want is,when i close the application the service must also close and when i resume the application the service must start.

but now it is creating two instance of the same service when i close and open the application.

**Service**

```
public class SignalRService extends Service {
    private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    private HubProxy mHubProxy;
    private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
    private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    public Boolean is_service_connected = false;
    public  String ProfileId;
    public  String profileToken;
    public  String CompanyID;
    public  String DisplayName;
    private Context context;

    public SignalRService() {
        mHubConnection = new HubConnection("chatHub");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("service", "Inside oncreate  - service");

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("zupportdesk", MODE_PRIVATE);
        ProfileId = prefs.getString("ProfileId", "Not defined");
        profileToken = prefs.getString("profileToken", "Not defined");
        CompanyID = prefs.getString("companyId", "Not defined");
        DisplayName = prefs.getString("DisplayName", "Not defined");
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("service", "service start  - service");
        int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startSignalR();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mHubConnection.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Unbounding", "SignalRservice Service unbound");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Return the communication channel to the service.
        Log.d("service", "onBind  - service");
        startSignalR();
        return (IBinder) mBinder;
    }

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SignalRService getService() {
            // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
            return SignalRService.this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * method for clients (activities)
     */
    private void getIncommingcht(){
        Log.d("Inside : ", "getIncommingcht - service - Method");
        mHubProxy.invoke("addOperatorsToGroup", ProfileId, CompanyID, "true", profileToken);
        mHubProxy.invoke("GetIncomingChatQueue",ProfileId, profileToken);
     //   mHubProxy.invoke("getselectedVisitors", ProfileId, CompanyID, profileToken);
        mHubProxy.invoke("getOtherActiveChat",  ProfileId, CompanyID, profileToken);
    }

    public void select_Active_Visitor(String visitor_id, String ProfileId, String CompanyID, String DisplayName, String profileToken, String startTime){
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        mHubProxy.invoke("selectVisitor", visitor_id, ProfileId, CompanyID, DisplayName, timeStamp, profileToken, startTime);
    }

    private void startSignalR() {
        // Create a new console logger
        Logger logger = new Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message, LogLevel level) {
                Log.d("Log Message : ", message);
            }
        };
        // Connect to the server

        HubConnection conn = new HubConnection("https://MY URL/", "", true, logger);
        // Create the hub proxy
        HubProxy proxy = conn.createHubProxy("chatHub");


        mHubProxy = proxy;
        Subscription subscription = proxy.subscribe("getVisitorResponse");
        subscription.addReceivedHandler(new Action<JsonElement[]>(){
            public void run(JsonElement[] eventParameters) throws Exception {
                    Log.d("getVisitorResponse-data", String.valueOf(eventParameters[0]));
                    Log.d("getVisitorResponse-time", String.valueOf(eventParameters[1]));
                IncommingFragment.getVisitorResponse(eventParameters[0]);
            }
        });

        Subscription subscription1 = proxy.subscribe("recieveIncomingChat");
        subscription1.addReceivedHandler(new Action<JsonElement[]>(){
            public void run(JsonElement[] eventParameters) throws Exception {
                Log.d("IncomingChat_data", String.valueOf(eventParameters[0]));
                IncommingFragment.receivedincommingchats(eventParameters[0]);
            }
        });

        Subscription subscription3 = proxy.subscribe("getOtherActiveChats");
        subscription3.addReceivedHandler(new Action<JsonElement[]>(){
            public void run(JsonElement[] eventParameters) throws Exception {
                Log.d("getOtherChats - data", String.valueOf(eventParameters[0]));
                OtherFragment.getOtherActiveChats(eventParameters[0]);
            }
        });

        Subscription subscription4 = proxy.subscribe("removeChatQueue");
        subscription4.addReceivedHandler(new Action<JsonElement[]>(){
            public void run(JsonElement[] eventParameters) throws Exception {
                Log.d("removeChatQueue - data", String.valueOf(eventParameters[0]));
              IncommingFragment.removeVisitor(String.valueOf(eventParameters[0]));
            }
        });


        Subscription subscription6 = proxy.subscribe("StartTransfer");
        subscription6.addReceivedHandler(new Action<JsonElement[]>(){
            public void run(JsonElement[] eventParameters) throws Exception {
                Log.d("Transfer_visitorID", String.valueOf(eventParameters[0]));
                Log.d("Transfer_receivername", String.valueOf(eventParameters[1]));
                Log.d("Transfer_receiverID", String.valueOf(eventParameters[2]));
            }
        });



        /*proxy.subscribe(new Object() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void recieveIncomingChat(RecieveIncomingchats recieveIncomingchats) {
                MainFragment.receivedincommingchats(recieveIncomingchats);
                Log.d("hit:", "Hit on receive Incoming chats");
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void serviceStatus(boolean temp){
                Log.d("service_status", "status called");
            }
        });*/



        // Subscribe to the error event
        conn.error(new ErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the connected event
        conn.connected(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("CONNECTED");
                is_service_connected = true;
                getIncommingcht();
            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the closed event
        conn.closed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("DISCONNECTED");
            }
        });

        // Start the connection
        conn.start().done(new Action<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Done Connecting!");
            }
        });

        // Subscribe to the received event
        conn.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(JsonElement json) {
                System.out.println("RAW received message: " + json.toString());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**Activity**

```
public class ChatsTab extends AppCompatActivity {


    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;


    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public static SignalRService mService = new SignalRService();
    private boolean mBound;
    private HelpLiveo mHelpLiveo;
    private ApplicationEnvironmentURL applicationEnvironment;
    public  static String ProfileId;
    public  static String profileToken;
    public  static String CompanyID;
    public  String DisplayName;
    private Context context;
    public String BASEURL;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chats_tab);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        initNavigationDrawer();

        applicationEnvironment = new ApplicationEnvironmentURL(this.context);
        context = this.getApplicationContext();


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("zupportdesk", MODE_PRIVATE);

        ProfileId = prefs.getString("ProfileId", "Not defined");
        profileToken = prefs.getString("profileToken", "Not defined");
        CompanyID = prefs.getString("companyId", "Not defined");
        DisplayName = prefs.getString("DisplayName", "Not defined");

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);




        if(!isMyServiceRunning(SignalRService.class)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, SignalRService.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }

        setCannedResponsesURL(ProfileId, CompanyID);
        new getAllcannedResponse().execute(profileToken);

    }


    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public void initNavigationDrawer() {

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                switch (id){
                    case R.id.home:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Home",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.settings:
                        Intent intent_settings =  new Intent(getApplication(), Settings.class);
                        startActivity(intent_settings);
                        break;
                    case R.id.canned_responses:
                        Intent intent2 =  new Intent(getApplication(), CannedResponses.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"canned responses",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.Operators:
                        Intent intent =  new Intent(getApplication(), Operators.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.logout:
                        finish();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView tv_email = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_email.setText(DisplayName);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
                super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new IncommingFragment(), "Incoming");
        adapter.addFragment(new ActiveFragment(), "Active");
        adapter.addFragment(new OtherFragment(), "Other");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


    /********************************* Service Methods ********************************************/

    private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            Log.d("Activity : ", "Inside service connected - Activity ");
            // We've bound to SignalRService, cast the IBinder and get SignalRService instance
            SignalRService.LocalBinder binder = (SignalRService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
            Log.d("Activity : ", "bound status - " + mBound);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mService=null;
            mBound = false;
            Log.d("Activity : ", "bound disconnected - status - " + mBound);
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
            Log.d("Activity : ", "bound disconnecting - status - " + mBound);

        }
        mService.onDestroy();
    }

    /**********************************************************************************************/






}
```

Comment: `"but now it is creating two instance of the same service"`, no, a service is a singleton: you cannot have two or more instances of your service

Answer (score 0):

In your Main activity create a method

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> SignalRService) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (SignalRService.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and make a check in Main Activity oncreate method

```
if(isMyServiceRunning(SignalRService.class)== true){
        // do nothing
    }else{
        // Start your service
    }
```

Hope it will solve your problem.